# How can I get this function to work on old jquery?

Tags: jquery

Using it with jquery 1.6.4 it doesnt work , with the newer versions it works fine.
Becasue I'm using a older jquery version I get error

> TypeError: $(…).on is not a function

http://jsfiddle.net/w0jekdL6/18/

```
$(".amount").on("keyup", function(){
    var valid = /^\d{0,5}(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(this.value),
        val = this.value;
    var pos = this.selectionStart - 1;

    if(!valid){
        if(typeof this.lastValid != "undefined") {
            this.value = this.lastValid
            this.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
        } else {
            this.value = "";
        }
    } else {
        this.lastValid = val;
    }
});
```

Comment: The real answer is to use a newer version of jQuery, there's no reason to use a version that is several years old.

Comment: i have try that , but unfortunately it breaks other stuff

Comment: Then you should probably replace the other stuff to newer stuff as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.keyup()` instead of `.on()`: (according to [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) this will also work for the new versions of jQuery)

```
$(".amount").keyup(function(){
    var valid = /^\d{0,5}(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(this.value),
        val = this.value;
    var pos = this.selectionStart - 1;

    if(!valid){
        if(typeof this.lastValid != "undefined") {
            this.value = this.lastValid
            this.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
        } else {
            this.value = "";
        }
    } else {
        this.lastValid = val;
    }
});
```

jQuery's `.on()` was only added in version 1.7

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work - see [jQuery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/)

`$(".amount").keyup(function () {...});`